# Convergence of series. Does the hint help?

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find value for $x$ for which the series converges,

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^k}{k!}x^k$$

Can I use the following fact?

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{k!}{\sqrt{2\pi k} (\frac{k}{e})^k} = 1$$

With the ratio or root test don't get a solution nor see a way to use the hint.

Answer (score 5):

You don’t need Stirling’s approximation:

$$\left|\frac{\frac{(k+1)^{k+1}x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}}{\frac{k^kx^k}{k!}}\right|=\frac{(k+1)^k}{k^k}|x|=\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k|x|\;,$$

and you should be able to evaluate that limit as $k\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Brian M. Scott has pointed out that the Ratio Test works smoothly, giving radius of convergence $\frac{1}{e}$. So the only issues are at $x=\pm \frac{1}{e}$.

For $x=\frac{1}{e}$, the Stirling formula works well. A Limit Comparison with $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ proves divergence.

For $x=-\frac{1}{e}$, we may need a little more than the basic Stirling formula. The signs in the sum alternate, and the absolute value of the terms goes to $0$. To apply the Alternating Series (Leibniz) Test, we need to show that the terms are ultimately decreasing in absolute value. This is dealt with by the term $\frac{1}{12n}$ in the [asymptotic expansion.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates)

Comment: Actually the expansion with a term $1/(12n)$ is not needed to solve the case $x=-1/\mathrm e$, since the natural, elementary, computation shows that the terms are decreasing (starting at $k=1$, not only "ultimately") because $\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k\leqslant\mathrm e$ for every $k\geqslant1$.

Comment: Yes, that was what I did. The ratio test. But, as the hint was given, I felt like I needed to use it somewhere.